# Different results with "xgboost" vs. "caret" in R

Tags: r, classification, cross-validation, caret, accuracy

I am new to R programming language and I need to run "xgboost" for some experiments. The problem is that I need to cross-validate the model and get the accuracy and I found two ways that give me different results:

With "caret" using:

```
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
library(caretEnsemble)
dtrain <- read.csv("student-mat.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
formula <- G3~.
dtrain$G3<-as.factor(dtrain$G3)
control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)
seed <- 10
metric <- "Accuracy"    
fit.xgb <- train(formula, data=dtrain, method="xgbTree", metric=metric, trControl=control, nthread =4)
fit.xgb
fit.xgbl <- train(formula, data=dtrain, method="xgbLinear", metric=metric, trControl=control, nthread =4)
fit.xgbl
```

Using the "xgboost" package and the following code:

```
 library(xgboost)
 printArray <- function(label, array){
 cat(paste(label, paste(array, collapse = ", "), sep = ": \n"), "\n\n")
 setwd("D:\\datasets")
 dtrain <- read.csv("moodle7original(AtributosyNotaNumericos).csv",        header=TRUE, sep=",")
 label <- as.numeric(dtrain[[11]])
 data <- as.matrix(sapply(dtrain, as.numeric))

croosvalid <-
xgb.cv(
data = data,
nfold = 10,
nround = 10,
label = label,
prediction = TRUE,
objective = "multi:softmax",
num_class = 33
)

print(croosvalid)  
printArray("Actual classes", label[label != croosvalid\$pred])  
printArray("Predicted classes", croosvalid\$pred[label != croosvalid\$pred])  
correctlyClassified <- length(label[label == croosvalid\$pred])  
incorrectlyClassified <- length(label[label != croosvalid\$pred])  
accurancy <- correctlyClassified * 100 / (correctlyClassified + incorrectlyClassified)  
print(paste("Accurancy: ", accurancy))
```

But the results differ very much on the same dataset. I usually get 99% accuracy on student performance dataset with the second snip of code and ~63% with the first one...
I set the same seed on both of them.

Am I wrong with the second? Please tell me why if so!

Comment: what is in your ctrl object? Are you setting the same seeds in caret as in xgboost? and try to make a reprod[ucible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for us.

Comment: what do you mean by ctrl object? I set the same seeds in the tests. I can't give the dataset I am using but is the same problem for example on students performance dataset [link](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00320/)

Comment: your caret model has option trControl = ctrl. how is control defined. Same goes for metric. Without those details we do not know how all the settings are.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have trainControl(method="cv", number=10) and metric <- "Accuracy"